# How do I test my api's Delete method using Mock?

Tags: c#, moq

I want to test the delete method using `Mock`, however when I pass an id to be deleted, it always returns `null`. How would I add a fake category in `Mock`?

```
[Fact]
public void Delete_Categoria_Return_OkResult()
{                       
    //Arrange  
    var controller = new CategoriasController(MockUnit.Object, mapper);

    MockUnit.Setup(m => m.CategoriaRepository.Delete(It.IsAny<Categoria>()));

    //var data1 = controller.Post(catId);
    //Act  
    var data = controller.Delete(1);

    //Assert  
    Assert.IsType<NotFoundResult>(data.Result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You’re not mocking the return which would explain why you’re getting null back from the mock of “delete”.
If you expect a return value you can add

```
.Returns(whateverObject);
```

And chain it to your mock setup.

Posting the controller code would also help in this situation